# Conditions for the derivative of a function to be a proper map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, differential-topology

Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a continuously differentiable function, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. In this case, the function
\begin{equation*}
Df:U \to L(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})
\end{equation*}
is continuous. Could one formulate conditions on $f$, which would suffice to assure that $Df$ is a proper map? Here by proper I mean the preimage of every compact set is compact.

Comment: Let's have a look at the easiest case, i.e. $n=1=m$ and $U=\mathbb{R}$. Then the question is equivalent to asking when $f'$ is proper. By the Heine-Borel theorem it is enough to check that preimages of bounded intervals are bounded. Hence, this forces $\lim_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty} \vert f'(x) \vert = \infty$ (and is also sufficient). This means $f$ needs to grow/decay very fast at infinity. In higher dimensions it would be enough to grow/decay in one direction.

Comment: Superlinear growth as $|x|\to\infty$: I am not sure if this is the kind of an answer you are interested in.

Comment: With this condition I am familiar and is also proven on a different SE post. Sorry if I was not precise enough. I am looking for any other equivalent condition.

Comment: Then I am not sure what are you looking for, even in the 1d case as in the above comment.